# Convert a binary string to int c#

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string result = "";
    foreach(char item in texte)
    {
        result += Convert.ToString(item, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    }
```

So I have string named result which is conversion of a word like 'bonjour' in binary.
for texte = "bonjour" I have string result = 01100010011011110110111001101010011011110111010101110010 as type integer.

And when I do

```
Console.writeLine(result[0])
```

I obtain 0, normal, what I expected, but if I do

```
Console.WriteLine((int)result[0])
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(result[0]))
```

I obtain 48!
I don't want 48, I want 0 or 1 at the type integer.

Could you help me please?

Comment: What result *do* you expect, and why? Is it just `Convert.ToInt32(someString, 2)`? If that is the ASCII for "bonjour", that is going to be 7 bytes; an int32 is 4 bytes; how do you want that to fit?

Comment: at int32 ! I want to obtain the 1 or the 0 at the type int32 but when I convert it to int 32 I obtain 48... I search for some method to just pick somestring[0] and have it as an interger without converting It, you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just subtract 48 from it!

```
Console.WriteLine(result[0] - 48);
```

because the characters digits 0-9 are encoded as 48 to 57.

If you want to access each bit by index, I suggest using a [`BitArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.8) instead:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("someString");
var bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
// now you can access the first bit like so:
bitArray.Get(0) // this returns a bool
bitArray.Get(0) ? 1 : 0 // this gives you a 1 or 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "23jlfdsa890123kl21";
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(a);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 8);
foreach (byte b in data)
{
    result.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
}
```

you can try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this 
`Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(result[0])));`

You're expecting it to behave the same as `Convert.ToInt32(string input)` but actually you're invoking `Convert.ToInt32(char input)` and if you check the docs, they explicitly state it will return the unicode value (in this case the same as the ASCII value).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx